# Angular takes wrong url for api after move to production

Tags: node.js, angular, proxy, url-rewriting

I am new to angular and know little to move production. I change some code in my local and it is working.

When I applied command `ng build --prod` it will generate production chunk files in node project `public` folder. I moved those files on live sever (Godaddy shared hosting) then site is working fine.

But when try to communicate with server (like login, register) with api then it will take my localhost URL `http://localhost:8080` instead of my domain URL.

This project is working fine in live server if I revert back to old code.

My `angular.json` file

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../server/serverAPI/public",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.png",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true
            }
          }
        },
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseUrl: 'https://example.com'
};
```

Comment: can you show how you are storing your api url may be you are storing it in environment.ts file

Comment: Its purely your environment file configuration..

Comment: I have store API URL in environment.prod.ts file as 'baseUrl'

Comment: please check your environment.prod.ts File.

Comment: Whether you have configured accordingly in your `angular.json` config file????

Comment: Yes i have configured `angular.json` file

Comment: @Pranav Gandhi Can you post that config??

Comment: please share your `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` files as well.

Comment: @PranavGandhi Try for `ng build --configurations  production `

Comment: @Subburaj It is not working. It throws error "unknown option"

Comment: @PranavGandhi Try for `ng build --configuration  production` typo mistake remove `s` from configuration

Comment: @Subburaj I have tried your method but not working.

Comment: @PranavGandhi were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try `ng build --configuration=production` as this is what your angular json has defined as a "production configuration".

Comment: I have tried this method but not working. also I tried `ng build --prod --configuration=production` it is also not working

Comment: Did you try this exact syntax? I noticed the ones above where missing the `=` sign between configuration and production.

Comment: Yes I have tried same exact syntax with `=` and also tried without `=` both are not working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'r storing your configuration in `environment` and do not add `fileReplacements` in production configuration so check your `angular.json` production config `fileReplacements` it should be

```
"production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```

Comment: if so then check your api url is not hard coded or share some code how you 'r calling your api and your angular.json